# codeigniter $this->load->vars between controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi found free source code based in codeigniter,

i have a controller in codeigniter some code is this:

```
    class front extends main
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load_main_vars();

        }


        private function load_main_vars()
        {
            $vars['title'] = $this->option->get('title');
            $vars['keywords'] = $this->option->get('keywords');
            $vars['description'] = $this->option->get('description');
            $this->db->order_by('category_name', 'ASC');
            $this->db->where('category_active', 1);
            $vars['categories'] = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_state' => 1))->result();
            $this->load->vars($vars);
        }
}
```

then i have another controller that extends front(code above):

```
    class Site extends front
    {


        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

        }

        function index()
        {

            $vars['site'] = $this;

            $this->view('site/index', $vars);
        }
}
```

my question is why i have to use `this $vars['site'] = $this;` in Site controller to use vars array added in front controller and pass to view,

thanks

Comment: What do you get when `var_dump($site)` in view file?

Comment: undefined, its supposed try to pass an object to the view?

Comment: To answer to question, because in parent controller variables are stored in pseudo variable this. $vars['site'] is local variable of index method, even not variable of whole Site class, so you want to dedicate widelly available values created in core front class to some variable you need to use in your view. Are you sure it is working or there is some error?

Comment: hi, thanks, really works without errors, at front controller get $vars array info from database, and at Site controller define  $vars['site'] = $this; at the view you have something like: <meta name="description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($description) ?>"> that is $vars['description'] = $this->option->get('description'); from front controller, ihave read you can pass arrays and objects to views but dont really understand not experienced developer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your code would work in CI at all and I'm going to only answer your question

A controller can't extend another controller,CI does not allow it, instead you need to create a My_controller.php in your application/core directory,add nessecary codes there and extend that class in your controller,now for start I'm going to give you an example based on your code

**application/core/My_controller.php**

```
class Main extends CI_controller {
    // methods and vars....
}

class Front extends Main {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load_main_vars();
    }

    function load_main_vars() {
        $vars = [];
        //assigning some vars to $vars
        $this->load->vars($vars);
    }
}
```

so now you can create your controller:

**application/controllers/Site.php**

```
class Site extends Front {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->view('site/index'); // now all vars are accesable in your view
    }
}
```

THis is the correct way to accomplish what you want in CI

Comment: hi,thanks for response, yes main extends CI_controller in my code aswell, this example works and is codeigniter.

Comment: your example works perfect thanks, but i see what it does is to pass site object, to use another method of site controller   <?php $site->list_news() ?>, is a correct way to do it, thanks

Comment: I did not understand your second comment

Answer (score 0):

Your example is far far away from secure application. 
Dedicating `$this` to some variable that is going to output is NOT RECOMMENDED. 
In that variable is stored many private data such are database credentials 
and you won't to deal with allowing view file have those. 
If I should make decision I would rate that application as least safe application in CodeIgniter world. Select that source code as dangerous insecure.

1. Never output `$this`
2. Never output `get_instance()`
3. Read first two rules again

Instead that:

In core controller make an array that you would have approach over.
It can be top level core class so you could have that array in children classes.

```
class Front extends Main
{
    public $data = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['front_vars'] = $this->load_main_vars();
    }


    private function load_main_vars()
    {
        $vars['title'] = $this->option->get('title');
        $vars['keywords'] = $this->option->get('keywords');
        $vars['description'] = $this->option->get('description');
        $this->db->order_by('category_name', 'ASC');
        $this->db->where('category_active', 1);
        $vars['categories'] = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_state' => 1))->result();
        $this->load->vars($vars);
    }
}

class Site extends front
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->view('site/index', $this->data['front_vars']);
    }
```

}

In strict coding pay attention on capital cases of class names (and files) and on visibility of methods.